# Joining Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables namely Students & Hobbies with following structure and records:

```
ID,Name
-----------
9,Peter

10,Steve


ID,Hobby
-----------------
9,dancing

9,singing

10,learning
```

I want to JOIN these tables and get a unique record from table Students.
I am doing this right now which evolves duplicate records:

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM Students a
LEFT JOIN Hobbies h ON a.ID =h.ID
```

This gives :

```
Name
----------
Peter
Peter
Steve
```

I got the reason, this is because, the table Hobbies has two records of ID=9 , that is why duplicate records are evolved, but how to retrieve a single record? Please help.

I want this:

```
Name
-----------
Peter 
Steve
```

Comment: PLease read an SQL tutorial e.g.: http://www.sql-tutorial.net/

Comment: Why join the tables if all you want are the two names in the Student table?  It seems like "SELECT Name From Students" would suit your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name
    FROM Students a
        LEFT JOIN Hobbies h
            ON a.ID = h.ID
    GROUP BY a.ID, a.Name
```

With the GROUP BY, you could then answer questions like "How many hobbies does each student have?"

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Hobbies
    FROM Students a
        LEFT JOIN Hobbies h
            ON a.ID = h.ID
    GROUP BY a.ID, a.Name
```

Comment: but sir, this eliminates students with same names?

Comment: @sqlchild: Then include an element (`ID`) that makes them unique. I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not the way a JOIN should be used.

left joining an unreferenced table on a constant gets you nothing.

the answer to the question you asked is "use a DISTINCT clause":

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name FROM Students a LEFT JOIN Hobbies h ON a.ID = 9
```

...but really, I'm pretty sure this is not what you want to do.

based off the comments, I believe what the OP's intent was something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.Name
FROM
    Students a
WHERE
    a.ID = <Student ID>;
```

... AND , for the hobbies reference:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.ID,
    a.Name
FROM
    Students a
INNER JOIN
    Hobbies h ON h.ID = a.ID
WHERE
    h.Hobby = <Hobby Name>;
```

Comment: which one is unreferenced here?

Comment: the hobbies table is not referenced in the select, so a left join to the hobbies table is vestigal; it does nothing.

Comment: but sir, if i use DISTINCT then, the two students with same name are not displayed? what to do now

Comment: the question is, what are you TRYING to do?  what is the significance of the hobbies table you're joining to?  What do you want to see?  How are you planning on using it?

Comment: actually i have a filter drop down in which all hobbies are listed, so when a user selects a hobby and searches, then students with selected hobby are listed because i add the WHERE clause in the query if any hobby is selected , but when no hobby is selected ,then  there is no WHERE clause, which brings duplicacy

Comment: that's two different queries.  I'll update my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `distinct` keyword:

```
SELECT distinct a.Name
FROM Students
etc....
```

It eliminates duplicate rows, so you'll only get one of each name.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicates because Peter has 2 hobbies. If you want a single record per User do this:

```
select * from Student where Id in (
Select DISTINCT Id from HobbY)
```